# CSS animations suspended on anchor click on iOS8 Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, css-animations

When using CSS animation for progress indicator on anchor click, this animation gets suspended on iOS Safari. Basically I want to use CSS spinning animation for visual feedback when user clicks on anchor links or form submit buttons. This works nicely in most browsers, except on iOS 8 Safari, which suspends the CSS animation right away.

CSS:

```
.spinner {
 border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  -webkit-animation: rotating 0.6s infinite linear;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#mylink').onclick = function(e) {
 document.querySelector('#spinner').classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://deelay.me/3000?http://google.com">Anchor with delay
</a>
<span id="spinner" class="hidden spinner"><span/>
```

Here is a Codepen with simulation:
http://codepen.io/asavin/pen/NPWbjw

Question - is it a feature? Is there any workaround?

Update: one workaround is to use animated GIF instead :D Updated codepen with GIF example. Run it on mobile to see how CSS animation will get stuck, and GIF won't.